# Index Error: list out of range on html table web-scrape - Python

Tags: web-scraping, index-error

I appreciate this has been asked many times but I've been stuck here for quite a while.

I'm trying to take all the data from a table on a website and put it into a pandas dataframe.

I've written the code to do the web scraping but for some reason i'm getting the error whilst trying to write to my variable.

```
import requests
import requests
url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices/stocks/summary/fundamentals.html?fourWayKey=GB00BCDBXK43GBGBXASX1'

page = requests.get(url).text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# print(soup.prettify())

all_tables = soup.find_all('table')

right_table = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'table_dati'})
tbl1 = right_table[0]

A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
E = []
F = []

for row in tbl1.find_all('tr'):
  cells = row.find_all('td')
  A.append(cells[0].find(text = True))
  B.append(cells[1].find(text = True))
  C.append(cells[2].find(text = True))
  D.append(cells[3].find(text = True))
  E.append(cells[4].find(text = True))
  F.append(cells[5].find(text = True))
```

Here's the error:

```
A.append(cells[0].find(text = True))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Appreciate the help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you see the html code, your first iteration doesn't have `td` (is the `thead`), so when you are trying to get the first element, it doesn't exist, because cells are empty.

This is the first row:

```
<tr>
   <th class="name">Income Statement</th>
   <th>
      31-May-13 <br>( £
      m&nbsp;)
   </th>
   <th>
      31-May-14 <br>( £
      m&nbsp;)
   </th>
   <th>
      31-May-15 <br>( £
      m&nbsp;)
   </th>
   <th>
      31-May-16 <br>( £
      m&nbsp;)
   </th>
   <th>
      31-May-17 <br>( £
      m&nbsp;)
   </th>
</tr>
```

You can surround with try, except, or select the `tbody`.

Based on your code, you can add to the `find_all()` a list of tags, and 
then jump when the length of the cells list is less than 6, but for the future it's better to try to create lists dynamically, instead of everything being fixed.

```
for row in tbl1.find_all('tr'):
    try:
        cells = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
        if len(cells) < 6:
            continue
        A.append(cells[0].find(text = True).strip())
        B.append(cells[1].find(text = True).strip())
        C.append(cells[2].find(text = True).strip())
        D.append(cells[3].find(text = True).strip())
        E.append(cells[4].find(text = True).strip())
        F.append(cells[5].find(text = True).strip())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print(A)
```

The output is:

```
[
  "Income Statement",
  "Revenue",
  "Operating Profit/(Loss)",
  "Net Interest",
  "Profit Before Tax",
  "Profit After Tax",
  "Profit After Tax",
  "PROFIT FOR THE PERIOD",
  "Minority Interests",
  "Equity Holders of Parent Company",
  "Earnings per Share - Basic",
  "Earnings per Share - Diluted",
  "Earnings per Share - Adjusted",
  "Earnings per Share - Basic",
  "Earnings per Share - Diluted",
  "Earnings per Share - Adjusted",
  "Dividend per Share"
]
```

Comment: that's only the very first row though? so what would happen on each other row when there are no th tags? I figured it would not be as important to pull the headings.

Comment: @NthA I have edited the answer, check if it's helpful.

Comment: yes that's what I'm aiming for thanks. but wouldn't it just skip over the th row if I don't add it to the find_all? Also, does len(cells) = 6 just ensure I'm only looking at tr/th from within the table? I'm not sure on why it needs to be there if I'm already only looking at rows from within the table tag.

Comment: @NthA yes if you don't want the <thead> data, if you don't add the <th> tag, it is going to skip. If you analyze the table structure, there are <tr> (rows) that contains only one element, so ensuring that the length is 6 we are not going to get this elements.